# Bootstrap popover is word wrapping

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am using a popover, and the popovers on the right are wrapping text for some reason causing them to be on top of eachother, and I am not sure what to do about this. I like the popover on the left, that is how I want the right ones to look. What can I do to fix this?

[image: Screenshot]

**The Left One**

```
<div class="form-group" 
    data-trigger="manual" 
    data-placement="left" 
    data-toggle="popover" 
    title="" 
    data-content="">
```

**The Right One**

```
<div class="form-group" 
    data-trigger="manual" 
    data-placement="right" 
    data-toggle="popover" 
    title="" 
    data-content="">
```

All I am doing is getting the form group `fg`, and doing this:

```
var fg = $("#" + item).closest("div.form-group");
$(fg).popover("show");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by just doing this. If there is a better way please let me know.

```
$(".popover").css({
    display: "inline-block",
    whiteSpace: "nowrap"
}).find(".arrow").css({
    top: "50%"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Discovering this issue on my own, I found that this is caused by the element somehow limited by its parent container on the right side. So it will get as small as possible as the text allows it.

So I just allowed it to grow wider to the right. It will still be limited by the max-width which is configured in Bootstrap.

For my case I fixed it with the following CSS

```
.popover {
    right: -100%;
}
```

I suggest to limit it to another container to not get any side effects: `.myContainer .popover {}`